# PNG overlay on basemap through imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to overlay a .png file of a geospatial mask over a basemap created through matplotlib. The mask should cover everything in the basemap that's outside of an imported shapefile of the focus region I'm studying. It does cover things outside of my focus region, but...when I attempt to overlay the mask on the basemap AND turn on the state, coast, and country boundaries to test my accuracy, the mask and its boundaries don't match up with the base, and I'm not quite sure why. I use the extent and zorder arguments, but the problem doesn't seem to lie with these keyword arguments.

I originally created the mask by exporting a .png of the figure (alpha = 1.0) with the exact same parameters (lat/lon boundaries, etc), and then used GIMP to make the portions included in the shapefile transparent.

[image]

```
def makeBasemap(lon, lat, param):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set_position([0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    ax.axis('off')
    llcrnrlon = 278.
    llcrnrlat = 37.
    urcrnrlon = 307.
    urcrnrlat = 50.
    m = Basemap(resolution = 'i', projection = 'lcc', 
            lat_0 = 10., lon_0 = 291.5, llcrnrlon = llcrnrlon, 
            llcrnrlat = llcrnrlat,
            urcrnrlon = urcrnrlon, urcrnrlat = urcrnrlat)
    m.ax = ax
    x,y = m((lon-360.),lat)
    pcmap = cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
    pp = m.contourf(x, y, param, 100, cmap=pcmap, extend='both')
    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()
    m.drawstates()
    im = m.imshow(plt.imread('nafsemask.png'), zorder = 10, 
              origin = 'upper', extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])
    return fig, m, x, y

fig, m, x, y = makeBasemap(lon, lat, param)
```